# WP Nested Shortcode Render Issue

Tags: wordpress

I am having a nested shortcode like below

`[boc]
   [boc_section title='Bieren Alcoholvrij' category='9']
   [boc_section title='fusten' category='11']
[/boc]`

When i try to get **boc_section** args i am not getting correctly. its been html encoded

`'category' => string '&#8217;9&#8242;' (length=15)
  'include' => string '' (length=0)
  'title' => string '&#8217;Bieren' (length=13)`

how i can get the exact value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say that wordpress can't texturize the content of the shortcode. `no_texturize_shortcodes` takes a list of shortcodes that don't need to be texturized.

```
add_filter( 'no_texturize_shortcodes', 'ignore_boc' );

function ignore_boc( $list ) {
  $list[] = 'boc';
  return $list;
}
```